# Javascript parse/split string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have `str = '10E'`

I want to get like this `['10','E']` number and letter

when i have tried `str.split('')`
I have got 
 `["1", "0", "E"]`

How to do what i want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `String.prototype.match()` with `RegExp` `/\d+|[a-z]+/ig` to match one or more digits or one or more a-z characters case insensitive

```js
var str = "10E";
var res = str.match(/\d+|[a-z]+/ig);
console.log(res);
```